# I get weird output for passing float value for 'a'

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, overloading

In the below program if try to assign float value to variable 'a', I get weird value in second line of output, which has nothing to do with 'a'.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void add( int , int );
void add( float , int );

int main()
{
  int a, b;
  float c;

cout << "Enter a, b, c - ";
cin >> a >> b >> c ;

add( a , b );
add( c, b );

return 0;
}

 void add( int a, int b){
    cout << "a + b = " << a + b << endl;
 }

void add( float a, int b){
  cout << "b + c = " << a + b << endl;
}
```

Sample Input:

> 2.4 2 2

Sample output:

> a + b = 2
>
> b + c = 4.59121e-41

I added

> cout << a << endl << b << endl << c<< endl;

before calling functions, this particular line gives

> 2
>
> 0
>
> 4.59135e-41

Please explain this output. Why b=0?

Comment: You don't check whether `cin >> a >> b >> c ;` succeeds. If it fails, you're operating on junk.

Comment: What exactly makes you think you *can* type a floating point value when your program expects to read an integer?

Comment: You don't think `2.4 + 2 = 2` is weird? Always initialise your variables, and check that input succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

When the code is reading a value into an `int` and the input is `2.4`, it reads the `2` then hits the decimal point and stops; a decimal point is not a valid character for an integer input. So `a` gets the value 2. Then the code tries to read the next integer value into `b`, and that fails, because there are no digits, only the decimal point. After that, any further attempts to read will also fail, because of the previous failure.